# Create pandas dataframe from list of lists

Tags: python, pandas, python-docx

I am trying to use docx python to combine multiple word documents which only containing tables. The code looks for all docx files in the designated folder and creates a list of the data. However, I am stuck in converting this data from a list to a pandas dataframe.
[A link to the tables that I am trying to copy into is here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kMAGXtgqYvo0EJabNxw-hQxNe66d9T1b).
The code I have worked on is here:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import os
import csv
from docx import Document
import glob

def read_docx_tables(filename, tab_id=None, **kwargs):

    def read_docx_tab(tab, **kwargs):
        vf = io.StringIO()
        writer = csv.writer(vf)
        for row in tab.rows:
            writer.writerow(cell.text for cell in row.cells)
        vf.seek(0)
        return pd.read_csv(vf, **kwargs)

    doc = Document(filename)
    if tab_id is None:
        return [read_docx_tab(tab, **kwargs) for tab in doc.tables]
    else:
        try:
            return read_docx_tab(doc.tables[tab_id], **kwargs)
        except IndexError:
            print('Error: specified [tab_id]: {}  does not exist.'.format(tab_id))
            raise

path = 'C:\\data\\' # use your path
filelist = glob.glob(path + "/*.docx")

li = []
for file in filelist:
    df= read_docx_tables(file)
    li.append(df)
print(li)
```

if I try the code: data = pd.concat(li) at the end the following error occurs: TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type ''; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: instead of `li.append(df)` try `print(type(df))` and see what is getting returned. Also, consider adding type hints to your functions, mypy might be able to point out your problem before you even run this code.

Comment: Hey Dan, Thanks for the suggestion. Will definately look into this. As for print(type(df)) the output was "<class 'list'>"

Comment: The error messages tells you it needs to be of type DataFrame or Series, maybe you wanted `li.append(pd.concat(df))`? Or better yet, put the concat in the return value of read_docx_tables